# DNS Migration to Azure DNS from Powerdns

Tags: domain-name-system, powerdns, azure-dns

We are using powerdns, I am looking into exporting all our zones and records to MS DNS, I am test exporting zones via phpmyadmin on my powerdns server.

I dont think MS DNS played nice with .sql .csv files (export options on phpmyadmin). Is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mention MS DNS, but I assume you mean Azure DNS across the board?

Answer (score 0):

I think that asking PowerDNS to produce the zone data for you rather than you going directly to its database will probably be easier in terms of generating something that can be easily be processed by other tools.

One readily available option for importing zone data into Azure DNS appears to be [`az network dns zone import`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-import-export) using the Azure CLI tools.
That tool reads a zone file, which you (assuming you allow yourself to perform zone transfers from PowerDNS) could produce using eg `dig @server zone AXFR >file` (removing the trailing SOA, ie `+onesoa` with modern dig, as necessary).

Another alternative would be writing a script that uses the [PowerDNS REST API](https://doc.powerdns.com/authoritative/http-api/index.html) (provided you run a modern version) to read zones and the [Azure DNS REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/dns/) to recreate corresponding zones on the Azure side.